# HIVE query logs location

Tags: hive

I am find very difficult to locate the HIVE query logs, basically i want to see what queries were executed.

Basically i want to find the queries in this state:

```
select foo, count(*) from table where field=value group by foo;
```

Comment: Executed *how*? Using Hive CLI (fat client, log file is local) or HiveServer2 (thin client, log file is on server)?

Answer (score 4):

From [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-QueryandDDLExecution):

> `hive.exec.scratchdir` Default Value:
>
> - `/tmp/${user.name}` in Hive 0.2.0 through 0.8.0
> - `/tmp/hive-${user.name}` in Hive 0.8.1 through 0.14.0
> - `/tmp/hive` in Hive 0.14.0 and later
>
> This directory is used by Hive to store the plans for different map/reduce stages for the query as well as to stored the intermediate outputs of these stages
>
> `hive.start.cleanup.scratchdir` Default Value: false

Answer (score -1):

Execute the query with below command

```
hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DRFA --hiveconf hive.log.dir=./logs --hiveconf hive.log.level=DEBUG -e "select foo, count(*) from table where field=value group by foo"
```

It will create a log file in  logs folder. Make sure that the logs folder exist in current directory.